# Efficiently reduce the size of groups in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which I am grouping based on the names of each row using the groupby function. I then want to reduce each group to a given size. I then add these groups back into a database to use for other processes. Currently I am doing this in a for loop but this seems really inefficient. Is there a method which pandas has to do this more efficiently?

```
grouped = df.groupby(['NAME'])

total = grouped.ngroups

df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in grouped:

    target_number_rows = 10

    if len(group.index) > target_number_rows:
        shortened = group[::int(len(group.index) / target_number_rows)]
        df_final = pd.concat([df_final, shortened], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the name and apply a `sample` (that'll take randomly N within that group) where N is either your desired amount or the complete amount for that group, eg:

```
out = df.groupby('NAME').apply(lambda g: g.sample(min(len(g), target_number_rows)))
```

Otherwise, take the first N or last N, eg:

```
out = df.groupby('NAME').head(target_number_rows)
# or...
out = df.groupby('NAME').tail(target_number_rows)
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I am hoping to get evenly spread values in the group (rather than random), hence the method I am currently using. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @James what about: `df.groupby('NAME').apply(lambda g: g if len(g) <= 10 else g[::len(g) // 10])`

Comment: Thanks a load, this does work, although, my understanding is lambda just loops in the background anyway so not sure if its any quicker. certainly more efficient coding though

Comment: you avoid the multiple `concat` calls, that looks like the biggest win. (Those could be avoided in the original code too, of course). Following the desire path (apply) leads to more efficient code here.